# How to use Coldfusion Administrator API Security.SetUser() method

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to create an Admin  user in ColdFusion 10 using the [Administrator API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html). Below is my code:

```
<cfscript>
 // Create an object of administrator component and call the login method
 adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator");
 adminObj.login("Password1");
 myObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.security"); 

 myObj.setUser(username="ramesh"
                , password="Password1" 
                , allowadminaccess="True"
                , Roles="Server Settings > Scheduled Tasks"
              );
</cfscript>
```

But it throws an error:

> The ROLES argument passed to the setUser function is not of type
>   array.

How do I pass the roles as an array?

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking it ;-) Just put the string inside an array as usual, by enclosing it in square brackets.

```
myObj.setUser( Roles = [ Roles="Server Settings > Scheduled Tasks" ]
                , ...
             );
```

See documentation: [Creating and using arrays implicitly](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09f0b-7ff8.html#WSf01dbd23413dda0e4c54bc751200f68de53-7fff)